# Blacking out a JTextField as it's written onto a JTextField[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, jtextfield

For a wheel of fortune game that I'm making, the game board is composed of an array of 56 `JTextField[]`s, with a method that prints out the current puzzle onto this `JTextField[]`. What I'm trying to do is cover up those letters when the puzzle is read onto the `JTextField[]` so that the player can, of course, not see the solution. I've tried setting the background to `Color.BLACK` after the program has determined what puzzle it will be putting on, and this worked so some degree, however the actual text faded grey, as to NOT be covered by the new background, and when I tried to set the background to grey, the text, of course, remained black. Ideally, I'd love for the spaces within the puzzle to not be covered with black. Here's a little visual of what I'm looking for:

`[P] [A] [S] [T] [R] [A] [M] [I] [ ] [S] [A] [N] [D] [W] [I] [C] [H]`

If that were to be the puzzle, anywhere there is a letter, should be completely blacked out, but the spaces kept white as they are.

Here is the code for the class all of this is happening in.

```
package wheelOfFortune;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

 public class letterBoard extends JPanel
                            implements ActionListener                   
 {
     private static int TEXT_FIELD_COUNT = 56;
     private static int SUIT_COUNT = 1;
     private static JTextField[] fields, p;
     private Box[] boxes = new Box[SUIT_COUNT];
     private static final String wheelFoods[] = {//bunch 'o' puzzles};
     private static final String wheelHouse[] = {//bunch 'o' puzzles};
     private static final String wheelMovies[] = {"//bunch 'o' puzzles};
     private static final String wheelPeople[] = {//bunch 'o' puzzles};
     private static final String wheelPlaces[] = {//bunch 'o' puzzles};
     private static final String wheelRandom[] = {//bunch 'o' puzzles};
     private Color yungMoney = new Color(0, 180, 100);
     private static String puzzle;
     private static List<JTextField> field;
     private static String[][] puzzles = {wheelFoods, wheelHouse, wheelMovies, wheelPeople, wheelPlaces, wheelRandom};
     private static String[] puzzled;
     public static String cat;

public letterBoard()
{
    fields =  new JTextField[TEXT_FIELD_COUNT];
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,299));
    setBackground(yungMoney);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,14));
    panel.setBackground(yungMoney);
        for (int i =0; i < boxes.length; i++)
        {
            boxes[i] = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            for (int j=0; j< TEXT_FIELD_COUNT/SUIT_COUNT; j++)
            {
                int index = i * (TEXT_FIELD_COUNT/SUIT_COUNT) + j;
                fields[index] = new JTextField("    ");
                fields[index].setEditable(false);
                fields[index].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                fields[index].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
                fields[index].setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 24));
                fields[index].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                panel.add(fields[index]);
            }
        }
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,2),"WHEEL OF FORTUNE"));
    add(panel);
}
public static String findPuzzle()
{
    for(int i=0; i<puzzles.length;i++)
    {
        puzzled = puzzles[(int) Math.round(Math.random() * (puzzles.length-1))];
        for(int j=0; j<puzzled.length; j++)
        {
            puzzle = puzzled[(int) Math.round(Math.random() * (puzzled.length-1))];
        }
    }
    return puzzle;
}
public static void reset()
{
    findPuzzle();
    field = new ArrayList<>(puzzle.length());
    for(int index=0; index<fields.length;index++)
    {
        fields[index].setText(null);
    }
    for(int k=0;k<puzzle.length();k++)
    {
        fields[k].setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 32));
        String character = Character.toString(puzzle.charAt(k));
        fields[k].setText(character);
        field.add(fields[k]);
    }
}
public static String getCat()
{
    if (puzzled.equals(wheelFoods))
    {
        cat = "FOOD  &  DRINK";
    }
    if(puzzled.equals(wheelHouse))
    {
        cat = "AROUND  THE  HOUSE";
    }
    if(puzzled.equals(wheelMovies))
    {
        cat = "MOVIE  TITLES";
    }
    if(puzzled.equals(wheelPeople))
    {
        cat = "PEOPLE";
    }
    if(puzzled.equals(wheelPlaces))
    {
        cat = "PLACES  AROUND  THE  WORLD";
    }
    if(puzzled.equals(wheelRandom))
    {
        cat = "RANDOM  STUFF";
    }
    return cat;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    //game logic
}
}
```

Within this code: the constructor makes the actual game board, `findPuzzle()` determines randomly what puzzle for the game to use from the arrays of puzzles in the instance variables, `reset()` clears the current board, and prints out a new randomly selected puzzle onto the board, and `getCat()` displays the category on a separate, unrelated `JTExtField`. What I need is for the spaces with letters in them (`String character` is a one-character long string that `letterBoard` uses to fill `JTextField[] fields` with the puzzle) to be completely blacked out, but spaces in the puzzle remain white. Thank you!
Note: the program runs through a main class, `wheelGUI`, and the `reset()` method is hooked up to a `JButton` within `wheelGUI`. Don't think posting the code for `wheelGUI` will be helpful.

Comment: Use the fields disabled text color instead...[`JTextComponent#getDisbaledTextColor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDisabledTextColor%28%29) or change the fields disabled text color to black...

Comment: Fixed blacking out everything (including spaces for the time being) by using `fields[k].setForeground(Color.BLACK);` and `fields[k].setBackground(Color.BLACK);`. Working on spaces now.

Comment: Yeah, that works to...

Comment: Don't use all static variables and methods. This is a sign of a bad design.

Comment: @camickr This is my first all-eclipse project after about 9 months of 5 hours a week of a Java class. I probably bit off a bit more than I could chew with this project, so for the time being, I'm only concerned with it functioning. I hear what you're saying, though. If I had some more experience under my belt, and a looser time constraint, I would go through and make sure everything is efficient and "eloquently" coded. :P